# How to declare different properties in different methods of the same unit test class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I would like to have a single unit test class to test the initialization of a class `@ConfigurationProperties("...") MyConfig`, given different sets of configuration properties.

For example:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyConfig.class })
@DirtiesContext // to force re-initialization of context
class MyConfigTest {
  @Autowired
  MyConfig myConfig;

  @Test
  @UseProperties("my-config.prop1=foo") // Looking for something like this?
  void test1() {
    assertThat(myConfig).doesSomething(...);
  }

  @Test
  @UseProperties("my-config.prop1=bar")
  void test2() {
    assertThat(myConfig).doesSomethingElse(...);
  }

  @Test
  @UseProperties("my-config.prop1=foobar")
  void test3() {
    assertThat(myConfig).doesSomethingTotallyDifferent(...);
  }
}
```

(Obviously I've totally made up the `@UseProperties` annotation, it was just to explain what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out a solution in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-multiple-configuration-properties-test)

The [test](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-multiple-configuration-properties-test/blob/main/src/test/java/com/wouterlefever/stackoverflow/configtest/config/MyConfigTest.java) can use different sets of properties which are mapped using an `ObjectMapper`.

```
final Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
final Object map = yaml.load(resource.getInputStream());
final ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
final String myConfigAsString = ow.writeValueAsString(map);
final MyConfig myConfig = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(myConfigAsString, MyConfig.class);
```

One downside is that the `ObjectMapper` doesn't recognize the prefix of the `Configuration` class (since it's not loaded as a bean) so you have to use an empty string, or don't fill in the value and remove indentation from your yaml.